# message in setFlash is empty

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have this code but the flash message is displayed incorrectly.

I want to display the message in:

```
http://xxx/cake/ ----(add action)
```

but actually the message is shown in:

```
http://xxx/cake/users/ ----(index action)
```

How can i solve this? I don't have any view to activation. I just want redirect to the add action and display the flash message after that.

---

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function add() {

    }

    public function activation() {
        $email = $this->request->query['email'];
        $codeLink = $this->request->query['code'];

        if($this->User->activationAccount($email, $codeLink)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Success'));///should be shown in add
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error.'));//should be shown in add
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
        }
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
```

Comment: you can try to do it using Session. And just after showing the value unset the session flash message.

Comment: Well, this is because a session of facebook connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just destroy this session:

```
array
  'fb_400xxxxxxx96_state' => string 'ce3xxasdxxxxxxasdasdxxxxxxxf' (length=32)
```

---

```
    public function add() {
        $this->Session->destroy();

        //some code

    }
```

Comment: You dont need to destroy the whole session, you can just call $this->Session->flash(); which will delete it, so it wont be shown when going to index after adding. Usually this flash() is put in the layout, so all pages show the message.

Comment: I Agree with @Ceeram answer. That's the best way to clear the flash messages. If you destroy the Session, then all the data stored in the session will be destroyed, which is not the best way. Because your login sessions, shopping cart (if exists) also will be destroyed with that.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should have a look at [this tuto](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) which cover this